# make auto-complete searchable drop-down don't want to display list on click just on search

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, drop-down-menu

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv9mo66a/6/)

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">
 <ui-select tagging ng-model="vm.selected" theme="bootstrap">
  <ui-select-match p laceholder="Pick one...">{{$select.selected.value}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="val in vm.values | filter: $select.search">
      <span ng-bind-html="val.value | highlight: $select.search"></span>
    </ui-select-choices>
 </ui-select>
</div>


var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.select', 'ngSanitize']);

app.controller("myCtrl", function() {
 vm = this;
 vm.isLoaded = false;
 vm.values = [{
  'key': 22,
  'value': 'Kevin'
 }, {
  'key': 24,
  'value': 'Fiona'
 }];
 vm.selected;
});
```

this is work fine but now i want to display list just on search don't want to display on click only on search word in search box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv9mo66a/7/)

After a lots of experiments i found the answer of my question

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.select', 'ngSanitize']);

app.controller("myCtrl", function() {
vm = this;

vm.funcAsync = function(query) {

    if (query === null || query === ""|| query.length<1) {
        return;
    }

 vm.isLoaded = false;
 vm.values = [{
 'key': 22,
 'value': 'Kevin'
  }, {
 'key': 24,
 'value': 'Fiona'
  }];
  vm.selected;

 };

});
```